# What's the meaning of sss and sssd in mysqli oo prepare statements?

Tags: mysqli

I have been learning mysqli object oriented method, although I am confused sometimes now I need to blind some variable for insertion and I search on how to do so but I got some code with something like:

```
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $email, $handle, $mobile);
```

and other like

```
$stmt->bind_param('sssd', $code, $language, $official, $percent);
```

Now I am totally confused. I learn on a website that sss means number of variable and object type, can someone explain better I have many variable to blind and they are of different type.

Answer (score 5):

The characters represent the [data types](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php#refsect1-mysqli-stmt.bind-param-parameters) passed to the query:

```
i - integer
d - double
s - string
b - BLOB
```

in this query:

```
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $email, $handle, $mobile);
```

the variables are three strings ($email, $handle, and $mobile).

This query has three strings, and the final variable is a "double":

```
$stmt->bind_param('sssd', $code, $language, $official, $percent);
```

More information about MySQL [data types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-types.html) and [numeric types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/numeric-types.html).